# How to send AWS SES email notification from php Application

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have deployed a php application on ec2. We have also configured the ses settings. Now can any share me the settings used in our application to send the bulk mail. I have gone through different settings but totally confused, some people recommend phpmailer, some recommend AWS SDK for PHP.
Please help me. Write now we are using the gmail account to send the email and using the below settings.

```
 $config = array();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    //$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'host';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'test@gmail.om';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '....';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = 'TRUE';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $this->email->initialize($config);
```

Can i simply replace the settings with aws ses settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is use SES as your SMTP mailer, it really is just a drop in replacement for a regular SMTP server (in your case gmail).

Using the AWS SDK is also an option, and opens up some more SES-specific functionality, but having uses SES for many years on many projects, I have never felt the need, and never felt the need to add in that complexity.

The one thing you *might* get confused on, is you do not use your regular AWS credentials for this, you need to specifically generate SMTP credentials from the SES section of the AWS console, and then use them for you smtp_user and smtp_pass - they look identical to regular AWS credentials, hence the possible confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have already generated the aws smtp credentials which i will use for user and paaword.

Comment: Dear, I am using the below mentioned settings but could not receive the email
.
$config = array();
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
        $config['smtp_user'] = '....';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = '';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
        //$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = 'TRUE';
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from('noreply@test','Noreply');
    }